# Magento: Product Move from cart to Wishlist

Tags: php, magento, shopping-cart, mage

I am trying to catch the event of move cart item to wishlist. I tried `wishlist_product_add` and `wishlist_product_item` events. But they not work on cart page. I want to save the custom options of product in wishlist. But when i move product from cart to wishlist all the options data are lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following event

```
       <wishlist_item_add_after>
            <observers>
               <cop_wishlist_price_options>         
                    <class>AAA_Addon_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>addProductPriceOptionsToWishlist</method>           
                </cop_wishlist_price_options>
            </observers>
        </wishlist_item_add_after>
```

and in observer, you can have access to wishlist and quote. copy data/options form quote to wishlist items.

```
public function addProductPriceOptionsToWishlist($observer){

try {

    $wishlist = $observer->getEvent()->getWishlist();   
    $itemId = (int) $this->_getRequest()->getParam('item');

    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');


        $quote_item = $cart->getQuote()->getItemById($itemId);
        if (!$quote_item) {
            Mage::throwException(
                Mage::helper('wishlist')->__("Requested cart item doesn't exist")
            );
        }

        $productId  = $quote_item->getProductId();

    $buyRequest = $quote_item->getBuyRequest();
    $buyRequestData = $buyRequest->getData();


    if($buyRequestData):

    $additional_op = $quote_item->getOptionByCode('additional_options');
    $additional_op = $additional_op->getData();

    $wishlist_item = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->load($productId,'product_id');


    //save additonal options to wishlist-options        
    $modelRes_w_item_op = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item_option');
    $modelRes_w_item_op->setWishlistItemId($wishlist_item->getId());
    $modelRes_w_item_op->setProductId($productId);
    $modelRes_w_item_op->setCode('additional_options');
    $modelRes_w_item_op->setValue($additional_op['value']);
    $modelRes_w_item_op->save();

    endif;


    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
    }


}
```

Comment: Which function in wishlist observer removes product from wishlist if it is added to cart ?

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you implement an event logging system so that you can see exactly what events are being fired.

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/choosing-a-right-event-to-observe/

You will then be able to see all events fired and choose the best one for your observer to hook into

Answer (score 0):

Use the event "wishlist_add_product".

Below is the "dispatchEvent" which is used in the method of adding products to the cart wishlist.

```
Mage::dispatchEvent(
            'wishlist_add_product',
            array(
                'wishlist' => $wishlist,
                'product' => $product,
                'item' => $result
            )
        );
```